# form.field.value fail to display any information

Tags: django

I'd like to edit an article detail page,

If the request method is `get`, pre-formulate the form with data

```
def edit_article(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CommentForm(instance=article)
    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, "article/article_detail_edit.html", context)
```

The template

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"   value="{{ form.title.value }}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content" class="col-sm-1 control-label" >Content</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="10" cols="30">{{ form.content.value }}</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Unfortunately, the form is blank after I click the edit link:

[image]

I test the code with

```
if request.method == "GET":
    form = CommentForm(instance=article)
    print(vars(form.instance))
```

It print all the data

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10c977438>, 'id': 1, 'owner_id': 1, 'block_id': 1, 'title': 'Time and Tide', 'content':....}
```

I passed the form to context

```
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, "article/article_detail_edit.html", context)
```

The article model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (1,  'normal'),
        (0, 'deleted'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'content']
        widgets = {'content': forms.Textarea}


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
        widgets = {'body': forms.Textarea}
```

What's the problem with my code to display `form.field.value`?

Comment: Are you updating form in context? i.e: context['form'] = form

Comment: I passed form to context, it still does not show anything. @Bott0610

Comment: Can show your Article model?

Comment: ty, of course @Bott0610

Comment: Okay, that checks out, how about your CommentForm class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing an Article instance to a CommentForm. Try:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

Since CommmentForm has no title or content values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the form in the context to the template.

**Try:**

```
def edit_article(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CommentForm(instance=article)
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "article/article_detail_edit.html", context)
```

I hope this will help

Comment: I passed form to context